# Display Two cubes in WPF

Tags: c#

I want to display 2 cubes with one button click.firstly,first cube is displayed after sometime it is removed and display another cube in WPF application in C#,all operations should be  with one button click?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: _"...after some time..."_ Requirements as we all know and love them!

Answer (score 1):

Try that plz

## Xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Draw cube" Margin="167,260,161,0" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 6" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                    </DirectionalLight>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                                Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                                TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D2" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain2" Position="8 5 4" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain2" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                    </DirectionalLight>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain2"
                                Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                                TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain2">
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

## Code behind

you just need to use a timer inside your button event to change cube visibility

```
private Timer _timer;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewport3D1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    _timer = new Timer(1000); // Set up the timer for 1 seconds
    _timer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
}

public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        viewport3D1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        viewport3D2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    })); 
}
```

Comment: @user3759856 hope that's help you at least to be in the right way